# If $A\subseteq{}^\omega2$ is a Borel set, is $\{x\in{}^\omega2\!:(\exists y\in A)\ x\le y\}$ also a Borel set?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, cantor-set, borel-sets

For $x,y\in{}^\omega2$, let us write $x\le y$ iff $(\forall n\in\omega)\ x(n)\le y(n)$.
Let $A\subseteq{}^\omega2$ be a Borel set. Does it follow that $B=\{x\in{}^\omega2\!:(\exists y\in A)\ x\le y\}$ is a Borel set?

Comment: Note: to achieve the $\TeX$ spacing you want for “:”, use `\colon`.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf I use `\colon` only in map formulas since it prevents line breaking after ":".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. Consider the $[\mathbb{N}]^\omega$, the Polish space of infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, with the relative topology from $^\omega 2$ (where I'm identifying subsets with characteristic functions). By Exercise (27.16) in Kechris' *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, there exists a closed $F\subset [\mathbb{N}]^\omega$ such that
$$
F^* := \{H\in[\mathbb{N}]^\omega : \exists H'\in F (H'\subseteq H) \}
$$
is $\Sigma^1_1$-complete (hence not Borel). Therefore neither $F^*$ is Borel regarded as a subset of $^\omega 2$. The image of $F^*$ by the homeomorphism $H\mapsto \omega\setminus H$ is
$$
\{G\in {}^\omega 2 : \exists H'\in F (H'\subseteq \omega\setminus G) \}
$$
which equals $\{x\in{}^\omega2:(\exists y\in A)\ x\le y\}$ when taking $A:=\{\omega\setminus H' \in {}^\omega 2 : H'\in F \}$.

So the implication is false already for $G_\delta$ subsets $A$.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. In some sense, it is counterintuitive, as $B$ may be viewed as "more regular" than $A$.

Comment: I agree with you. But also, I recalled that the convex hull of a Borel set might be just analytic, and that situation is similar (with a stretch) to the present one.